# Quarkus application properties as kubernetes/openshift config map for native Image deployment

Tags: java, openshift, redhat, quarkus

I want to externalize quarkus application properties as config map in kubernetes/openshift native image deployment.
I know for Spring-boot we can use spring.config.location argument and refer using config map.
How can we do the same for naive executable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The application looks for an `application.properties` file in the `config` directory, sibling to the executable. So what you want is to:

1. Create a ConfigMap with a key called `application.properties`. The value under that key is your application configuration file.
2. Mount that ConfigMap into a `config` directory next to your executable. That is, if the executable is in `/app`, the ConfigMap should be mounted to `/app/config`.